# Isomorphism Type

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Given $G=\mathbb{Z}_{16}^{\times}$ then how does one go about to determine the isomorphism type of $G/ \langle15 \rangle$ and $G/\langle 9 \rangle$?

**Question:**
When you say $G/⟨15⟩$ has 4 elements, have you removed the elements $1,7,9,$ and $15$ from $G$? That is to say have you removed the elements who form subgroups of the same size as $⟨15⟩$ If so, is this what we want to do when $G/⟨a⟩$ in general?

**With regards to comment below**

Does this mean that we should count the order of say $3 (mod(16))$ when Dietrich Burde is speaking of "finding an element of order 4". If so, then would I be right to claim $G/⟨15⟩$ is C4 and $G/⟨9⟩$ is this as well?

Comment: The elements of $G/\langle 15\rangle$ are **cosets** of the subgroup $H=\langle 15\rangle=\{1,15\}$. There are four cosets:
$1H=\{1,15\}$, $3H=\{3\cdot1,3\cdot15\}=\{3,13\}$, $5H=\{5,11\}$ and $7H=\{7,9\}$, We are not removing anything. The number of elements goes down, because after moving over to the quotient group we no longer make a distinction between e.g. $7$ and $9$. Notice that $9H=\{9,7\}=7H$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Does this mean that we should count the order of say $3$ (mod(16)) when Dietrich Burde is speaking of "finding an element of order $4$". If so, then would I be right to claim $G / \langle 15 \rangle$ is $C_{4}$ and $G/\langle 9 \rangle$ is this as well?

Comment: No. It means that you should count the order of $3H$ in $G/H$. $(3H)^2=9H \neq 1H$ et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

$G$ may be represented by $\{ 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15\}$, and has $\phi(16)=8$ elements.
The subgroup $\langle 15\rangle$ equals $\langle -1\rangle$, since $15\equiv -1(16)$. Hence $G/\langle 15 \rangle$ has $4$ elements. There are only two different groups with $4$ elements: either $C_4$ or $C_2\times C_2$. If you find an element of order $4$, then your group is $C_4$, otherwise it is $C_2\times C_2$. The same applies for the group $G/\langle 9\rangle$. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) has the details.

Comment: The subgroup $\langle 15 \rangle$ may be represented by $\{1,15\}$, and so there are two elements. However, I am not sure how to proceed with this information.  As far as I am aware, isomorphism type means that one is only interested in listing groups up to group isomorphisms. For example, $G=\{-1,1\}$ is a multiplication group with two elements which is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_2$. In this case, if I am not mistaken, one would say that $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the isomorphism type of the (abelian) group G.

Comment: When you say $G/\langle 15 \rangle$ has $4$ elements, have you removed the elements $1,7,9$, and $15$ from $G$? That is to say have you removed the elements who form subgroups of the same size as $\langle 15 \rangle$ If so, is this what we want to do when $G/\langle a \rangle$ in general?

Comment: Just to continue on the same line of reasoning; as the order of $\langle 3 \rangle$ is $4$ am I right to conclude $G/\langle 15 \rangle$ has the isomorphic type of $C_{4}$?